# Sampling for Approximate Bayesian Computation without Simulation

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, posterior, approximate-bayesian-computation

I am trying to use ABC for a physical black box phenomenon. Both the input space and output space are 3D, and there is a proper distance function for the performance space (CIEL*A*B* ΔE). It is not possible to simulate this black box, therefore the samples need to be physically measured and evaluated. In addition, this measurement should be done in batches. I am wondering whether it's possible to perform ABC without a simulator and if it is an efficient approach for this problem.

Furthermore, is there an iterative sampling method for posterior that provides samples in large batches, e.g., Sequential Monte Carlo with many chains?

Comment: That sounds like a really tough problem. Have you thought about replacing simulating from an exact model for the underlying phenomenon with an approximate model instead  (that's either a big simplification, or does local pertubations around actually measured data points, or is e.g. some [Bayesian?] neural network that got trained on some real data to approximate sort of non-parametrically the underlying process)?

Comment: You need to specify what is available then, as the question is too unclear in its current state.